# date format removing 0

Tags: php, regex

How will i remove the 0 in my output i tried this code.

```
    $dates="2017-09-08";

    $formated_date=date("d-m-Y", strtotime($dates));

    Output:08-09-2017

My Expected Output : 8-9-2017
```

Comment: Open `date` function manual please.

Comment: See [PHP.net on `date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$dates="2017-09-08";
$formated_date=date("j-n-Y", strtotime($dates));
```

USE THIS